# ListView not working as expected in Android 7

Tags: android, listview, android-camera

I have got a very strange issue and I'm trying to fix it for many days.
My List view should show the data after right login credentials to application .
My list view code is working properly in android version below 7 but in android version 7 list view does not show any data.
Strange thing is that if I call `cameraIntent` (function in the code below) just after the login page and then turn down the camera , then list view shows all the data.
I have tried lot of other things but the only conclusion is that data appears only after I call `cameraIntent` once.

```
 private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
```

I have used two functions in my java code.
`Doit_function` extracts the data from the url (php script on the server to extract the data from the database) and parses the json (data returned by php script).

```
void doit_function()
    {

        request1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response1) {


                StringBuilder ob = new StringBuilder();


                parse_the_json(response1);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(arr_list.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YESssd on second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("employee_id", username);


                return hashMap;
            }
        };

        requestQueue1.add(request1);


    }
```

Other function is `populateUsersList()`. This function is used to populate the list 
and is called after `doit_function`.
Populate user list also contains a call to `camera_intent`.
If i remove the `cameraIntent` the code works fine in android version below 7.
I have put `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(700)` because I think it takes some time to load the data from the database server and if I remove this (`TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(700)`) line code doesn't work in any of the android version.

```
private void populateUsersList() {
        // Construct the data source

        CustomUsersAdapter1 adapter = new CustomUsersAdapter1(this, arr_list);
        //ArrayList<Entry> arrayOfUsers = Entry.getUsers();
        // Create the adapter to convert the array to views

        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(700);
            cameraIntent();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(arr_list.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Front_activity.this, Card.class);

                Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
                Log.e("YESSSS",Integer.toString(position));
                Entrynew temp = new Entrynew();
                temp=arr_list.get(position);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),temp.employee_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                i.putExtra("employee_id",temp.employee_id);
                i.putExtra("username",username);
                i.putExtra("url","https://tonichi-tws.com/Business_Card/php/entry.php");

                startActivity(i);
            }

        });

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `doit_function` is an async task and therefore your `populateUserList()` might be executed before the data is fetched. One alternative is to setup the adapter on your `onResponse()` or make a broadcast to tell you have finished fetching data.